# Obfuscation tool with click-once support

Tags: security, clickonce, obfuscation

I have found a lot of obfuscation tools with no clickonce support.

Could you provide vendors with click once support?
I would like to deploy obfuscated software at once without adding ANY extra line of code (pre-buid, post build etc)

p.s. I believe that is software related

Comment: What is "click-once" support?  Why is this an issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't speak for other obfuscation products, but this has been a request of customers of Dotfuscator.

An integrated method for obfuscating ClickOnce applications is not currently available but will be coming in the next major release of Dotfuscator.  I know this, because the task is currently assigned to me :) .

If there is anything in particular that you would like to see please feel free to let me know and I'll make sure to keep it in mind as I work on it.

Comment: OK, I'll ask you since the OP seems unresponsive and you claim its part of yolur product plan.  What is "ClickOnce"?

Comment: ClickOnce is a deployment technology from MS that makes it easy to run Winforms/WPF applications on clients by having users visit a certain URL which causes the the application to be installed on their system. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClickOnce or http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d(VS.80).aspx for more details.

Comment: Ideally I would like to be able to tick a box to say obfuscate in the click once wizard or publish settings. Then everything else works the same way, e.g. I can publish to an ftp site with right click on the project -> publish -> Finish and away it goes.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the manifests outside of Visual Studio using mageui (run mageui from the visual studio command prompt).  It requires a little more work, but you can create the manifests with the dll's post-compile.  If you want to make it easier after the initial setup, you can create a nant build file to do all the steps for you using mage (command line equivalent to mageui).

Answer (score 0):

I produce a piece of software called ClickOnceMore which can be used to create ClickOnce manifests from obfuscated assemblies. Its more user friendly than Mage and MageUI and has a command line version that can be included as part of a build process. I have several customers who use it in conjunction with obfuscators, particularly Dotfuscator.

You can find the software here: http://www.clickoncemore.net

Answer (score 0):

The Dotfuscator software included in Visual Studio 2010 will obfuscate your code and re-sign the manifests for you. Prior versions would obfuscate, but then you had to re-sign the manifests yourself.